# Bloquear Pagina com Login

Tags: php

Como fazer para que se a pessoa não estiver logado, ela não vai poder utilizar essa função a baixo, porque andei testando e se a pessoa por exemplo usa o link. O codigo redireciona ela para a tela de login, mesmo assim, ele ainda apaga o conteudo do ID

https://#####/####/adm_tabela_apagar.php?id=45

Ela consegue apagar, mesmo não estando logado como admin, apenas alterando os valores dos id's, ela consegue apagar todos os itens da minha tabela.

A função adm_tabela_apagar, abaixo:

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || $_SESSION['id'] == ''){
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Área restrita";
header("Location: login.php");
}

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);


    if(!empty($id)){
    $result_usuario = "DELETE FROM itenspreco WHERE id='$id'";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Item apagado com sucesso</p>";
        header("Location: adm_tabela.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Erro o usuário não foi apagado com sucesso</p>";
        header("Location: adm_tabela.php");
    }

}else{  
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Necessário selecionar um usuário</p>";
    header("Location: adm_tabela.php");
}
```

Comment: Em que momento você inicializa a sessão?

Comment: Em uma pagina anterior, que faz a conexão com essa ai

Comment: Pode postar o código referente a sessão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja tentou acrescentar um exit()? ele vai encerrar a execução do script, pode ser que resolva...

Uma forma mais segura de fazer isso seria registrar a sessão do usuario em um banco de dados e para cada pagina verificar o id da sessão (armazenar o id em algo como $_SESSION['id']), se o retorno da consuta for positivo processa a pagina se não, cai no header()..

```
if (1 == 0) {
    echo 'ok!';
}

else {
    header ('Location: http://www.google.com.br');
    exit();
}

echo 'não sera impresso';
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi é passado arquivo.php?id=45 tem como fazer da seguinte forma essa validação.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
         //Código de execução
}else{
    //Stop
}
```

Comment: Creio que não entendeu a questão.

Comment: Ele informou isso na pergunta dele https://#####/####/adm_tabela_apagar.php?id=45

Comment: Leia com um pouco mais de calma todo o problema.

Comment: Se eu dei essa solução eu li a pergunta, problema dele nem é Sessão é forma de exclusão, ta certinho a sessão dele se não existe manda de volta.

Comment: Problema dele é se o ID não existir como ele da um stop nisso? Exatamente isso que mostrei ah ele.

Comment: Hehehehehe, não vou negativar sua resposta, ela não resolve o problema. Parece me que você leu e releu o problema, agora falta fazer uma reflexão para atendê-lo melhor.

Comment: Creio eu que ele já resolveu